# jinja2 right align a float : formatting issue

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

i'm trying to align some floats, it works great if I use 'X' character as the fill parameter in the  [formatting doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) :

```
<ul>
{% for race in rrr[1] %}
<li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> {{ '{:X>5.1f}'.format(race.distance_number) }}km
<i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>{{ '{:.0f}'.format(race.elevation_number) if race.elevation_number is not none else '' }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If I use a X it aligns things well with

```
{{'{:X>5.1f}'.format(race.distance_number) }}
```

[image: aligned]

But if I use a space
`{{ '{: >5.1f}'.format(race.distance_number) }}` which ultimately is what I want, it's not aligned anymore

[image: not aligned]

is there any way to "fix" this ? is that a font issue ?

Comment: Multiple "normal" spaces in HTML are ignored. Your could try `&nbsp;` (non breaking space) instead of a normal space. But normally you would do this kind of formatting with css `text-align: center;`

Comment: In both cases i have the right number of characters : 'XX10.0km' or '  10.0km' and 'XXX5.0km' or '   5.0km' . That's why I thought it was the font. I'lll try to not right align with python but with css then